# Tratamento de strings com python e pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Estou tentando criar uma função que percorre um dataset e remove caracteres  das strings como ('?^*'), e retorna a coluna já corrigida dentro do dataset.

Como exemplo de dataset:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 'ds??', 'fgfs', 0],
                       [3, 'dsda#..*', np.nan, 1],
                       [np.nan, '1 ??d', np.nan, 5],
                       [np.nan, 'v2', 0, 4]],
                       columns=list('ABCD'))
'''
Gostaria de um função que retorna-se as colunas sem os caracteres #?,somente com números e letras 

eu preciso de uma função um pouco mais genérica , para o dataset todo tipo , que reconheça a coluna object e trata ela ,estou tentando fazer dessa forma .


 def tratar_str2(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        if df[col].dtype.name == df['object']:
            for k , v in enumerate(df['object']):
                df[v] = re.sub(r'(?<![a-z])-|-(?![a-z])', '',df[v], flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    return df
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o método ***replace*** de strings para substituir os caracteres que você quer. Para usar métodos de strings no pandas basta aplicar o método ***str*** na coluna de interesse. Exemplo removendo `?`:

```
df['A'].str.replace('?','')
```

Se você quer remover o mesmo caractere para todas as colunas basta usar um for loop (supondo 3 colunas, `A`, `B` e `C`):

```
for k in ['A','B','C']:
    df[k]=df[k].str.replace('?','')
```